# Pathogen not loading all bundles in Windows

Tags: vim

I'm trying to load two VIM plugins on Windows 7 x64 using Pathogen. The plugins are NERDTree and vim-ipython

NERDtree loads but IPython doesn't and I'm not entirely sure why. Any tips would help. See below for my directory structure and :scriptnames output

[image: Bundle Directory]
[image: scriptnames]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vim-ipython is a filetype plugin, as evidenced by the fact that its main content resides in an `ftplugin` folder.

It will not load, until you start editing a python file. Then it should load automatically.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the issue of it showing up in scriptnames but it still doesn't seem to work. One step at a time though. Thanks!